# How to SELECT only the most recent (and multiple) values once?

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm trying to find the people user id `1` has had a conversation with (as in, messages exchanged). I only need each of the other user's id once, but I'd like to get the resultants ids ordered by the date (or highest ID, since id is an incremental key) in which the latest conversation(message) of each user with user `1` happened. User `1` might be the one who sent the message or the one who received it, any case counts as a 'conversation' or interaction with other users.

Here's what I'm doing

```
    SELECT fromId AS userId FROM messaging
      WHERE toId = 1
    UNION
    SELECT toId AS userId FROM messaging
      WHERE fromId = 1
```

But of course, that only returns each user's id, but it doesn't return the results in the order in which the messages happened. For instance, if user had a conversation with user id 5 and the id of that message is higher than the conversation he had with user 6, then the order must be `5, 6`

Is there any way of doing this with just one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were reasonably close, just need to add an extra field to the union for the date, and then group by the id, and sort by the max time. like so:

```
select id, max(message_time)
  from
    (select fromid id, message_time
       from messaging
       where toid = 1
     union
     select toid id, message_time
       from messaging
       where fromid = 1
    ) q
    group by id
    order by max(message_time) desc;
```

Here's an example fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d248e/2

**edit as per comment request**

This query will get the most recent message for each conversation, as well as the message text.

```
select t1.id, t1.message_time, t1.message
  from
    (select fromid id, message_time, message
       from messaging
       where toid = 1
     union
     select toid id, message_time, message
       from messaging
       where fromid = 1
    ) t1
    left join
    (select fromid id, message_time, message
       from messaging
       where toid = 1
     union
     select toid id, message_time, message
       from messaging
       where fromid = 1
    ) t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.message_time < t2.message_time
    where t2.id is null
    order by t1.message_time desc;
```

The general gist of that one is the same as the earlier query - build a derived table that has just the userid, message date and this time also the message. Left join that derived table to itself (hence repeating the union query) on the user id, but also where the message time is greater. because we are left joining, if there is no message with the same userid, but greater timestamp, we are left with nulls in the second half of the result. this is what indicates that we have the most recent message time, as well as the text.  All that is left to do then is filter based on those null values, and sort.

[updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d248e/21)

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks. I know this isn't in the original question, but I guess it's not enough to be another one also, and I hope it's not a stretch, but can I also get the LAST message from each last result? (assuming there's a 'message' column). I tried just adding message to the main query and the query inside of the parens, but it returns the first one, I think. The message associated with the MAX date for each result, to put it simply.

Comment: That's more compicated - but i'll add that a bit.

Comment: @GreasyDonkey done. sorry for the delay.  there's likely to be a better way to get the results - but the best way would be to have a 'conversation' table i think, which lists participants in a conversation, and each message is then tagged with the conversation id.  thats the way skype does it.

Comment: Don't worry, it works great! I still can't fully wrap my head around SQL, I don't know why I find it harder to comprehend than other languages, but your help was great and I think I get this. I'll definitely check into that, looks like it'd be a more "flexible" way of structuring things. Thanks.